# How to resolve known_hosts file does not exist?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running a Jenkins container that communicates with a Docker host. I created a pipeline to utilize a GitHub repository. But when I do the build it gives an error and the following message is shown in the log:

```
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
Verifying host key using known hosts file
You're using 'Known hosts file' strategy to verify ssh host keys, but your known_hosts file does not exist, please go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure Global Security' -> 'Git Host Key Verification Configuration' and configure host key verification.
```

I generated ssh keys in the container. I added the public key on github and the private key for the git user used for the build.

In the container the generated keys are in the path: `/root/.ssh/`

I ran the following command in the container to test the communication with github: `ssh -T git@github.com`.

**command output**: Hi campos! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I am not understanding this error. Can you help me?

Comment: that message means that you can do file transfers but not get a shell...

Answer (score 0):

In the pipeline I changed master to main. This solved the problem.

[image]